# select all the rows from my table except the first 20 rows

Tags: mysql

I want to select all the rows from my table except the first 20 rows. How it possible? The total number of rows are not static.

```
SELECT statistics_id,title, user_name FROM (
    SELECT statistics_id,title, user_name FROM statistics ORDER BY statistics_id DESC 
    LIMIT(select count(*)from statistics )-20 
) sub
ORDER BY access_statistics_id ASC
```

I know 'LIMIT(select count(*)from statistics )-20'  is not a correct method. Please help.

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html read about limit function =\

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the documentation says (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/select.html) the following:

To retrieve all rows from a certain offset up to the end of the result set, you can use some large number for the second parameter. This statement retrieves all rows from the 96th row to the last:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl LIMIT 95,18446744073709551615;
```

so you could use something like

```
LIMIT 20, veryLargeNumber
```

Comment: why the downvote? I just copied and pasted the MySQL documentation!

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
   DECLARE v_max bigint unsigned default ~0;
   SELECT statistics_id,title, user_name 
   FROM statistics 
   LIMIT 20, v_max;
```

Answer (score 0):

After writing the select query u just have to include,

```
LIMIT 21,100;
```

21-Offset i.e from which row you want to start selecting and

100- is the Limit[Which you can set according to your need]

Answer (score 0):

You actually need:

```
SELECT 
  statistics_id, title, user_name 
FROM statistics 
ORDER BY 
  statistics_id ASC
LIMIT 20, 18446744073709551615;
```

**As per [MySQL Documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/select.html)**

> To retrieve all rows from a certain offset up to the end of the result
>   set, you can use some large number for the second parameter. This
>   statement retrieves all rows from the 96th row to the last:
>
> `SELECT * FROM tbl LIMIT 95,18446744073709551615;`

Comment: @OP: You accepted this answer on `2014-10-14 06:35:41Z`, and unaccepted the same on `2016-01-15 09:35:52Z` ? Did you find any wrong with it ???

Answer (score 0):

If your table grows fast, selecting all rows (with exception of first 20) is not a good idea. In such case, you should batch your query, and handle a subset of entries at a time, some thing like:

`SELECT * FROM tbl LIMIT 20,120;`

Answer (score -1):

Try using the offset option for the LIMIT syntax. you can read more about the LIMIT syntax at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html.

```
SELECT `statistics_id`
, `title`
, `user_name`
FROM `statistics` 
ORDER BY `statistics_id` ASC
LIMIT 20, 18446744073709551615
```